# Изображения товара в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу поставить изображения товару, но в админке, в настройках товара нету элемента "*Изображения товара*", в настройках экрана тоже не видно этого пункта, подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего такое может быть…

Comment: Может быть отключено отображение в "Настройки экрана", в правом верхнем углу экрана.

Comment: там вообще этого пункта нет

Comment: Смени тему на нормальную. Если в ней нет поддержки  даже такого, то и с другими вещами будут проблемы.

Comment: разрабатываю свою тему, поэтому так, подскажите если знаете как  это настроитть